# Laravel Conditional Statement: is when() efficient?

Tags: php, performance, laravel-5, conditional-statements, query-optimization

I would like to know about the efficiency / performance of using Laravel's new Conditional Statements `when()` that comes in the Query Builder functions.

Are they more efficient than a simple variable condition?

Example: i am filtering results with some radio and checkboxes, and they will provide many conditionals, i would like to know the most efficient way of applying them:

Simple conditional:

```
if($request->has('sale')) $query = $query->sale();
```

Laravel Conditional statement:

```
 query->when($request->has('sale'), function ($query){
     return $query->sale();
 })
```

Thanks in advance, cheers.

Docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#conditional-statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** The `when` function is little more than [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). It's not more efficient than regular conditionals, and (probably) not less efficient enough to worry about.

---

Let's have a look at the [`when` method's source code](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/738935bc42c52c4d7d65d07bcb2672408beff024/Eloquent/Builder.php#L738):

```
public function when($value, $callback)
{
    $builder = $this;

    if ($value) {
        $builder = call_user_func($callback, $builder);
    }

    return $builder;
}
```

As you can see, the `when` method does not do anything different than `if (<your conditional>)` and then calling the callback function supplied by you.

Because it does exactly the same as your simple conditional example, it cannot be *more* efficient. It will probably be marginally less efficient, because it involves two additional method calls -- however, this will so marginal that I would not worry about any performance impact. If you're concerned about efficiency, you should profile both implementations and only optimize if it proves to be a bottleneck.

The real reason for the `when` function's existence is [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). It allows you to conditionally add new constraints to a query without breaking the `QueryBuilder`'s fluent interface:

```
$q = $q
    ->when(isset($foo), function() use ($foo) { return $q->where('foo', $foo); })
    ->when(isset($bar), function() use ($bar) { return $q->where('bar', $bar); })
    ->when(isset($baz), function() use ($baz) { return $q->where('baz', $baz); });
```

As opposed to

```
if (isset($foo)) {
    $q = $q->where('foo', $foo);
}

if (isset($bar)) {
    // ...
```

In certain circumstances this might prove to be better readable (or not). In the end, whether to use `when()` or a simple conditional instead, is nothing more than personal taste.

Comment: Wow, now that's an answer. Thank you so much. Didn't knew about 'syntactic sugar'. By the way, what does TL;DR mean? did i posted the question in a bad format? i'm kind of new in here.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to StackOverflow! TL;DR means *too long; didn't read* and is often used as prefix for a short summary to a longer anwser.